# permutation, arrangement with restrictions, playing with vowels

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

in how many ways can the letters of the word "together" be arranged? In how many of these arrangements are all the vowels together?

i solver the first one:
(8P8)/(2P2 *2P2) =10080

but not sure with the vowels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with the first one: $\frac{8!}{2!2!} = 10080$, as there are $8!$ many permutations, and we can interchange both t's and both e's, so we get 4 times fewer.

Well, for the other one: there are 3 vowels that have to be together. Call all vowels together "V". Then we have to permute tgthrV (so 6 symbols) (where V stands for all the vowels). We have two t's so we get $\frac{6!}{2!}  =360$ different permuations of tgthrV.

But we have to replace V in every such permutation by a permutation of the actual vowels, of which there are 3 different ones (same formula: $\frac{3!}{2!} = 3$, or enumerate oee, eoe, eeo).

So we get 3 times as many, so $3 \times 360 = 1080$.

Comment: great explanation where i fully understand, thanks :D